# Open many files and plot colour by dataset in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am a newbie to `R` and I am sure this is simple, but I am not sure what terms to search for.

I have a series of data files in directories, each with the same format (tab separated, each has `X_DATA` and `Y_DATA` columns). I want to open them up and plot them with `ggplot2`, with each dataset having a different colour. I have tried the following, but it returns an error (also below).

**Script:**

```
require(ggplot2)

# ---
# open files
d_files <- list.files(pattern = '*.dat', recursive=TRUE)
d_list <- lapply(d_files, read.csv, sep = "\t")

## ---
# add a name attribute
for (i in seq_along(d_list)) attr(d_list[[i]], 'Name') <- d_files[[i]]

# ---
# join all of the files into a single dataset
d <- do.call('rbind', d_list)

# ---
# plot
p <- ggplot(data=d, aes(x=X_DATA, y=Y_DATA, colour=Name)) + geom_point()
ggsave(p, file="test.pdf", width=8, height=4.5)
```

**Output:**

```
Loading required package: ggplot2
Loading required package: methods
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Name' not found
Calls: ggsave ... sapply -> lapply -> eval.quoted -> lapply -> FUN -> eval
Execution halted
```

## EDIT:

Here is a `python` script to generate some data

```
from random import uniform
N = 100  # entries per file
M = 3  # number of files
for i in range(M):
    with open('%i.dat' % (i + 1), 'w') as f:
        f.write('X_DATA\tY_DATA\n')
        f.write('\n'.join((('%g\t%g' % (x, x ** (i + 1))) for x in (uniform(0,1) for j in range(N)))))
```

This `R` script shows what I would like, however, here, I have to explicitly type out every file. This is not appropriate for the working version.

```
# ---
# read each file and assign the dataset a name
d1 <- read.csv('1.dat', sep='\t')
d1$Name = '1.dat'
d2 <- read.csv('2.dat', sep='\t')
d2$Name = '2.dat'
d3 <- read.csv('3.dat', sep='\t')
d3$Name = '3.dat'

# ---
# combine datasets
d <- rbind(d1, d2, d3)

# ---
# plot
p <- ggplot(data=d, aes(x=X_DATA, y=Y_DATA, colour=Name)) + geom_point()
ggsave(p, file="test.pdf", width=8, height=4.5)
```

[image: Example]

From the original script, setting the following as per below works: `for (i in seq_along(d_list)) d_list[[i]][['Name']] <- d_files[[i]]` -- but does this not mean that I now have a text element called `Name` for *every* data point? This strikes me as not ideal...

Comment: Try removing the `p <-`, as you're assigning the ggplot call to a variable, not printing it. `ggsave` saves the last printed plot. Your second option is to step through the script, compared to running it in batch.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: This doesn't make a difference unfortunately. Also, if it leave the `p <-` in, but remove `colour=Name`, the plot is produced, but all of the points are black.

Comment: @DrDom: Unfortunately not. No change.

Comment: Sorry, I'm stuck without a reproducible example.

Comment: Doing `d1$Name="foo"` does set `Name` for every row. That's how `ggplot` likes to be fed.

Comment: @Spacedman I see, this seems like it is creating a substantial amount of redundant data -- is there another way to achieve the effect I am after?

Comment: 99% of the way to that particular nirvana is in my edit.

Comment: @BrT It's not really redundant data if you think of it as each point has a membership in a group, and that membership must be noted for each point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is total guessology because you haven't given us a reproducible example.

Let's read the first bit of the error message. Always a good idea:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Name' not found
```

Now, `Name` appears twice in your script:

```
for (i in seq_along(d_list)) attr(d_list[[i]], 'Name') <- d_files[[i]]
```

and

```
p <- ggplot(data=d, aes(x=X_DATA, y=Y_DATA, colour=Name)) + geom_point()
```

And I suspect what you are trying to do is add a `Name` column to the data frame (Comment your code!!!). This is not what R calls an 'Attribute'. In R, attributes are little additional bits of metadata you can stick on objects, and are also used for dimensions, row names, and column names (but not the actual data itself).

I think in your loop, do:

```
 for (i in seq_along(d_list)) d_list[[i]][['Name']] <- d_files[[i]]
```

to add a Name column.

A way that doesn't involve adding `Name` to every data frame is this:

```
ggplot()+geom_point(aes(x=X_DATA,y=Y_DATA,col=d_files[[1]]),d_list[[1]]) +
        geom_point(aes(x=X_DATA,y=Y_DATA,col=d_files[[2]]),d_list[[2]]) +
        geom_point(aes(x=X_DATA,y=Y_DATA,col=d_files[[3]]),d_list[[3]])
```

But try as I might I can't get this in a loop. Raaaage.

This almost works:

```
plots = laply(1:3,function(i)
    {geom_point(aes(x=X_DATA,y=Y_DATA,col=d_files[[i]]),d_list[[i]])}
)
Reduce("+",plots,init=ggplot())
```

But fails because ggplot evaluates `d_list[[i]]` for `i` at the time the geom is created, but evaluates `d_files[[i]]` when the geom is plotted. So you'll see the points from all three sets, but they all seem to come from `i=3`. If you set `i=2` and re-run the `Reduce` function you'll see them all seeming to come from the second dataset.

There's probably a way round that that doesn't involve making a character string and evalling it. Will call a guru...

Comment: Thanks for the effort. At the moment, my datasets aren't huge, so I will just add `Name` -- just figured there would be a way around it...

Comment: Does putting `force(i)` inside your anonymous function fix the problem of it only getting the last data?

Comment: No, it gives `i not found` on the `Reduce` step, which is the same as not having `force(i)` and not having an `i` in the top-level context.